# How to add 2 numbers display the result in HTML without Javascript

Tags: html, math

As the question, I'm coding such as (value x) * (value y) to directly display the result in HTML in software.

But the software doesn't support the script tag. can we simply use HTML tag achieve function.

In the software I have the subtotal example $55.25, but I want it shows $$65.00 (calculate by $55.25 / 0.85)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XxHT.jpg)

Comment: HTML is just a markup language - it cannot do calculations.

Comment: What software are you using that uses HTML but doesn't support `script`?

Comment: it's shipment software called shipstation, I am creating the packing slip template but it doesn't support the script tag

Comment: How are you creating the template? The [ShipStation API](https://www.shipengine.com/) seems pretty robust and looks like it can use command line (thus you can parse the data or pass it to another program) ...

Comment: ShipStation allow us to create template with HTML. The order date comes from  the NetSuite, however the the price had been modified by percentage before import into NetSuite, so ShipStation receive the price doesn't match to customer's purchase price which I expect to show the purchase price on the template.

Comment: Do you want to **add** or **multiply** or **divide**? You question seems to contradict with itself.

Answer (score 1):

HTML cannot do math - it is a markup/layout language. Whatever logic you are using that is creating the items to add to the template will need to also do the math and send the result to the template.